# How to search a list in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, search

I have a list like so:

```
List<string[]> countryList
```

and each element of the string array is another array with 3 elements.

So `countryList[0]` might contain the array:

```
new string[3] { "GB", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom" };
```

How can I search `countryList` for a specific array e.g. how to search `countryList` for

```
new string[3] { "GB", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom" }?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
return countryList.FirstOrDefault(array => array.SequenceEqual(arrayToCompare));
```

To simply establish existence, use `countryList.Any`.
To find the index of the element or -1 if it does not exist, use `countryList.FindIndex`.

Comment: Am i missing something as I don't have a FirstOrDefault method on my List<string[]> object, i have a Find and FindAll. And i don't have a SequenceEqual. I am using .NET 3.5

Comment: ah, i didn't have system.linq imported ... ups!

Answer (score 1):

```
// this returns the index for the matched array, if no suitable array found, return -1

public static intFindIndex(List<string[]> allString, string[] string)
{
    return allString.FindIndex(pt=>IsStringEqual(pt, string));
}


 private static bool IsStringEqual(string[] str1, string[] str2)
{
   if(str1.Length!=str2.Length)
      return false;
   // do element by element comparison here
   for(int i=0; i< str1.Length; i++)
   {
      if(str1[i]!=str2[i])
         return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Wrong... Equals method compares the references not the values inside of the array, so it will never find anything.